# How to make the screenreader read tooltip inside a table cell (td)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-readers

How do I make screenreader read the the tooltip inside a table cell?

Here is what I tried but screenreader ignores the title.

```
<td title="Hooray!" role="tooltip"><strong>✓</strong></td>
```

Comment: Technically, your tooltip is not **inside** the table cell, it's **on** the table cell (`<td>`). Also, by setting `role="tooltip"` on your `<td>`, you have essentially removed it as a cell in a table because it's no longer a `<td>` - it's now a tooltip. Hopefully that was just sample code of something you tried but I would definitely not do that.

Comment: When do you want the tooltip announced? When the user TABs to the table cell (which your sample code won't allow because it's not a focusable element) or when the screen reader user navigates between cells in the table (`ctrl+alt+arrowkey`)?

Comment: tabs to the table cell. Thanks.

Comment: Your example code does not have any keyboard focusable elements so the user won't be able to tab to the table cell.  Your question will need more details, perhaps a working code example.

Answer (score 0):

Use aria-label attribute

> The purpose of this technique is to provide a label for objects that
> can be read by assistive technology. The aria-label attribute provides
> the text label for an object, such as a button. When a screen reader
> encounters the object, the aria-label text is read so that the user
> will know what it is.

ref: [https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA6.html#:~:text=The%20purpose%20of%20this%20technique,will%20know%20what%20it%20is](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA6.html#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20this%20technique,will%20know%20what%20it%20is).

```
aria-label="Hooray!"
```